# Follow up Drupal path to PHP function

Tags: uri

How do I figure out which PHP function is called from a Drupal path/URL (e.g. "/mysite/?q=flag/flag/like/&destination=node/1&token=xyz")?

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out from the implementing module's implementation of `hook_menu`.

In your case, look for where Flag implements `hook_menu` (in the case of Flag 7.x-3.x you're looking at `flag.module` at around line 301. 
Next, look for where the module declares `$items['flag/%/%flag/%']`, and look for the `page callback` array key. You can see it says `flag_page`, so you can tell the menu callback is calling the `flag_page`.

You can find the Drupal 7 documentation for `hook_menu` [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7).

Comment: Yeah, thx. Exactly what I was looking for.